# Filling out a form and submitting in a UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, forms, uiwebview

I want to fill in a text box inside a UIWebView, so I am using the following code to do so;

```
NSString *inputipjavascript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('IP').value = '%@';", enterip];

NSString *result;
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:inputipjavascript];
result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('#GD').click();"];
```

The page which has the form on which I want to fill out automatically and submit is:

http://www.whatismyip.com/tools/ip-address-lookup.asp

The above code doesn't work at all, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most likely explanation based on the limited details of the context of your code, is that you are ignoring the asynchronous nature of the `loadRequest:` method and trying to execute your javascript commands before the DOM has loaded. Thus executing your commands on nothing. The `UIWebView` way to handle this is to use the `-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;` delegate method.

**Edit:** To "I did this already, but it didn't work.".

After examining the page at your link:`http://www.whatismyip.com/tools/ip-address-lookup.asp`. Your javascript is not compatible with the elements of your target webpage. For example here is the tag of the IP input field.

`<input type="text" name="IP" value="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx">`

And you are trying to use `getElementById('IP')` to get access to it. It has no `id` element so you are not referencing anything. The most precise specifier is the `name` element, it's value being `IP`. The first method that came to mind was `getElementsByName()`, then I just have to use element `[0]`.

For a quick test I threw a few lines in an IBAction for a test and they worked for me:

```
- (IBAction)enterAndPress:(id)sender {
    NSString *enterip = @"74.125.227.50"; // take that google
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByName('IP')[0].value = '%@';",enterip]];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByName('GL')[0].click();"];
}
```